# Rails 4 Error 422 on heroku with ajax button

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, heroku

My Rails 4 app works fine locally but when I deploy to heroku I keep getting the error "422 Unprocessable Entity" for a particular ajax request:

```
<%= button_to update_profile_picture_path(
                params: {
                  picid:    standardpicture.id,
                  callsign: character.callsign,
                  authenticity_token: form_authenticity_token # doesn't work with or without this
                }
              ),
              class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs',
              remote: true do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<% end %>
```

which hits this controller action:

```
def update_profile
  @character = Character.find_by(callsign: params[:callsign])
  standardpicture = Picturething.find_by(id: params[:picid])
  @character.build_profilepicture
  standardpicture.picture.recreate_versions!
  @character.profilepicture.picture = standardpicture.picture.profile
  @character.profilepicture.save!
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      redirect_to @character.sociable
    end
    format.js
  end
end
```

I've done everything suggested on SO:

**application_controller.rb**

```
protect_from_forgery # doesn't work with with: :exception or with: :null_session
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

I've also tried deleting cookies and clearing the cache.

**Request headers**

```
ResponseHeaders
X-Runtime   3.023140
Date    Mon, 21 Dec 2015 12:20:28 GMT
Via 1.1 vegur
Server  Cowboy
Strict-Transport-Security   max-age=31536000
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  1334
X-Request-Id    b4217519-49d0-4719-ad19-283b7160d6cd

RequestHeaders
X-CSRF-Token
3bvVUdzpR7vPprCaDH+jaFBZL/WH8s7kp82pg9yhUZFMdKM5oDVwkSPt75iCoXW1mA81lQk7f/NhKTLmrCCrCw==
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept  */*;q=0.5, text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

**Update**

The local logs don't have any errors but the production logs are complaining about the line

```
@character.profilepicture.save!
```

in the controller. It looks like MiniMagik doesn't think the file a a jpeg.

**Heroku logs**

```
2015-12-21T20:07:48.576449+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/update_profile_picture?authenticity_token=Ubzl991xI%2FZwp8ZVxBRRxJZ060yLqQwgd4Oyz0m3r4bAc5Ofoa0U3JzsmVdKyocZXiLxLAVgvTexZymqOTZVHA%3D%3D&callsign=bazley&picid=1" for217.38.149.159 at 2015-12-21 20:07:48 +0000
2015-12-21T20:07:48.579647+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PicturethingsController#update_profile as JS 
2015-12-21T20:07:48.579670+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"Ubzl991xI/Zwp8ZVxBRRxJZ060yLqQwgd4Oyz0m3r4bAc5Ofoa0U3JzsmVdKyocZXiLxLAVgvTexZymqOTZVHA==", "callsign"=>"bazley", "picid"=>"1"} 
2015-12-21T20:07:49.565800+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update_profile_picture?authenticity_token=Ubzl991xI%2FZwp8ZVxBRRxJZ060yLqQwgd4Oyz0m3r4bAc5Ofoa0U3JzsmVdKyocZXiLxLAVgvTexZymqOTZVHA%3D%3D&callsign=bazley&picid=1" host=websmash.herokuapp.com request_id=bd512b7f-9475-474a-a27b-265a558b5653 fwd="217.38.149.159"dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=975ms status=422 bytes=1607 
2015-12-21T20:07:49.545882+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 966ms (ActiveRecord: 9.1ms) 
2015-12-21T20:07:49.549053+00:00 app[web.1]:  
2015-12-21T20:07:49.549058+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Picture Failed to manipulatewith MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: Command ("identify -quiet -ping /tmp/mini_magick20151221-12-kc1te5.jpg") failed: {:status_code=>1, :output=>"identify.im6: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x23 0x3c `/tmp/mini_magick20151221-12-kc1te5.jpg' @ error/jpeg.c/JPEGErrorHandler/316.\n"}): 
2015-12-21T20:07:49.549060+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/picturethings_controller.rb:12:in `update_profile'
```

**character.rb**

```
has_many :standardpictures, class_name: "Picturething",
                            inverse_of: :character, 
                            foreign_key: "character_standard_id", 
                            dependent: :destroy 
accepts_nested_attributes_for :standardpictures 

has_one  :profilepicture,   class_name: "Picturething", 
                            inverse_of: :character, 
                            foreign_key: "character_profile_id", 
                            dependent: :destroy 
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profilepicture
```

**picturething.rb**

```
belongs_to      :character, class_name: "Character",
                            inverse_of: :standardpictures, 
                            foreign_key: :character_standard_id 
belongs_to      :character, class_name: "Character", 
                            inverse_of: :profilepicture, 
                            foreign_key: :character_profile_id 
mount_uploader  :picture, CharacterpicUploader
```

**uploaders/characterpic_uploaders.rb**

```
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick # Removed! See below
process resize_to_limit: [900, 900] # Removed!
version :profile do 
  process resize_to_fill: [230, 230] # Removed!
end 
# Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader: 
if Rails.env.production? 
  storage :fog 
else 
  storage :file 
end 
# Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.  
def store_dir 
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}" 
end
```

**Update 2**

Removing MiniMagick partially solves the problem - the ajax request goes through without error, returning this js:

```
$('#profilepic').html('<img src=\"https://websmash.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/picturething/picture/5/baz1.jpg\" alt=\"baz1\" />')
```

However the picture doesn't show up, there's just a broken link saying 'baz1'.